Use original input values if nothing is changed on a reactive table (datamods) in Shiny R
I'm trying to build a Shiny App to present some model simulations. The user should have the possibility to update all input variables to his own values.
The App has several tabs: first the simulation results and second the input data table. As long as nothing is changed on the inputs data table, the simulation should run with the original values.
The problem is that the calculation in the fist tab es not executed until clicking once on the second tab with the input data table.
I found out that it works fine if the input table is the first tab, but that is not what i want to have.
Here is a small example app showing the problem:
library(shiny)
library(datamods)
library(reactable)

#Create test dataframe
aa<-c("A","B","C","D")
bb<-c(1:4)
test_df<-data.frame(aa,bb)

#App####

#UI####
ui <- fluidPage(

navbarPage(title = "Test",
header=tags$head(tags$style(type='text/css', ".irs-grid-text { font-size: 10pt; }")),

             tabPanel(title = "Example",
                        mainPanel(
                          verbatimTextOutput("test_data")#,
                        )),
             tabPanel(title = "Input data",
    
                      mainPanel(
                        edit_data_ui(id = "id")#,
                      
                      ))

)
)

#Server####
server <- function(input, output) {
edited_r <- edit_data_server(
id = "id",
data_r = reactive(test_df),
add = FALSE,
update = TRUE,
delete = FALSE,
file_name_export = "datas",
var_labels = list(
aa = "name",
bb = "value"
),
var_edit=list("bb"),
reactable_options = list(
defaultColDef = colDef(filterable = TRUE),
selection = "single",
columns = list(
bb = colDef(name = "value", style = list(fontWeight = "bold"))),
bordered = TRUE,
compact = TRUE,
searchable = TRUE,
highlight = TRUE
)
)

output$test_data <-  renderPrint({
sum(edited_r()$bb)
})

}

# Run the application

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

My goal is that the result (in this example the sum) is directly calculated when the App is started. Currently the user has to click on the second tab and go back to the first to trigger the calculation.
Is there a way to define that the original inputs should be used as long as there are no changes?

In datamods::edit_data_server(), the output id of the table is constructed as [id]-table, where [id] is the parameter which is passed to edit_data_server.
In your case, you set id = "id" in edit_data_server(), so your table has id = "id-table". What you need here is suspendWhenHidden = FALSE, hence, if you add
outputOptions(output, "id-table", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

to your server, then the calculation result is visible already after starting the app.
